# Cannot save a variable of a editor script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello people i'm trying to save a field of a custom editor value is set in a combo box, i get a code from internet but i realized that the changes maded in the combo box doesn't save at all, i tried use the "Save" button, i tried to make serializedfield, but i'm new in C# and unity. Thanks for visiting have a nice day.

```
    using UnityEditor;
    using UnityEngine;


    [CustomEditor(typeof(DoorScript))]
    [System.Serializable]
    public class ButtonDropDownMenu : Editor
    {
        public override void OnInspectorGUI()
        {
            base.OnInspectorGUI();
            DoorScript script = (DoorScript)target;

            GUIContent arrayLabel = new GUIContent("Color");
            script.index = EditorGUILayout.Popup(arrayLabel, script.index, script.options);
            /*serializedObject.FindProperty("index").intValue = script.index = EditorGUILayout.Popup(arrayLabel, script.index, script.options);
            script.index = EditorGUILayout.Popup(arrayLabel, script.index, script.options);

            var properlyToSave = serializedObject.FindProperty("Index");
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(properlyToSave);
            serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();¨*/

        }
    }



using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Experimental.Rendering.Universal;

public class DoorScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private SpriteRenderer myColor;
    public Light2D doorLight;
    public Light2D doorPLight;

    [HideInInspector][SerializeField]
    public int index = 0;
    [HideInInspector][SerializeField]
    public string[] options = new string[]
    {
        "White",
        "Red",
        "Blue",
        "Cyan"

    };

    private void Awake()
    {
        myColor = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        ColorChanger();
    }

    void Start()
    {

    }

    private void ColorChanger()
    {
        if (index <= 0)
        {
            DoorsLights(Color.grey);
        }
        else if (index == 1)
        {
            DoorsLights(Color.red);
        }
        else if (index == 2)
        {
            DoorsLights(Color.blue);
        }
        else if (index >= 3)
        {
            DoorsLights(Color.green);
        }
    }

    private void DoorsLights(Color color)
    {
        myColor.color = color;
        doorLight.color = color;
        doorPLight.color = color;
    }
}
```

Edit:

I worked Perfectly i made a change instead of

```
index = EditorGUILayout.Popup(arrayLabel, script.index, script.options);
```

i used

```
 index.intValue = EditorGUILayout.Popup(arrayLabel, script.index, script.options);
```

Comment: Does it still not save when you uncomment `serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();`... that line should be necessary

Comment: i'll try again, give a minute Edit: isn't working yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update properties from a custom editor you'll want to use `SerializedProperty`. Like this:

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(DoorScript))]
public class ButtonDropDownMenu : Editor
{
    SerializedProperty index;
    void OnEnable()
    {
        index = serializedObject.FindProperty("index");
    }
...
```

Then make sure you're calling `serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();` when you're done:

```
public override void OnInspectorGUI()
{
    base.OnInspectorGUI();
    ...
    index = EditorGUILayout.Popup(arrayLabel, script.index, script.options);
    ...
    serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
}
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if this doesn't work

Comment: I worked Perfectly i made a change instead of  'code' index = EditorGUILayout.Popup(arrayLabel, script.index, script.options); 'code'

Comment: Glad! BTW you can use a ` to get the 'code' to format properly, my button for the symbol is on the top left of my keyboard